# FORECAST Function Range Updating

Tags: excel, function

I am trying to use the forecast function range to update as the days go by.
For example, if today is 12/16/16, I have my known x's and y's from 1/1/2016 to 12/16/2016.
Let's say 5 days from now, I open the spreadsheet, I need the known x's and y's to now capture the date from 1/1/2016 to 12/21/2016.
Is that possible?

In summary, I just need to have the forecast formula ranges update as the days go by to capture the new x's and y's as they "arrive"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: so far, I have the following: =IF(ISNA(L78),FORECAST(R78,$L$6:L77,$R$6:R77),0)

Comment: so far, I have the following: =IF(ISNA(L78),FORECAST(R78,$L$6:L77,$R$6:R77),0)  However, if I open the sheet tomorrow, the range will still be from rows 6 to 77, and not update to 6 - 78.